# Watchdog problem

Tags: arduino-mega

I am using Maniacbug Mighyty-1284p 16MHz in my project.
Here I used watchdog for safety.I used three command for watchdog.

```
1. wdt_enable(WDTO_8S);
2. wdt_reset();
3. wdt_disable();
```

Is it create any problem if I use "wdt_enable(WDTO_8S);" command two times (one after another without using wdt_disable();)

Comment: no. it only sets the registers. and the reason for setting it twice is?

Comment: @Juraj besides setting the registers, it also resets the watchdog timer if it is running. Still not an issue for the OP. Calling it twice is fine.